# what exactly is interface(struc) and interface(struc).function

Tags: go

Trying to do go koan, i got stuck in understanding the  interface(struct) syntax, what exactly
does it do ?
I came up with following fun program, which has further confused me on how is interface casting working :

```
package main

import "fmt"

type foo interface{  fn() }

type t struct { }
type q struct { }

func (_i t ) fn() { fmt.Print("t","\n") }
func (_i q ) fn() { fmt.Print("q","\n")}

func main() {
    _j :=  t{}
    _q :=  q{}

    // This is alright ..
    fmt.Print( _j.fn,"\n")           //0x4015e0     
    fmt.Print( _q.fn,"\n")       //0x401610     
    _j.fn()              //t           
    _q.fn()              //q           
    // both pointers same .. why ?
    fmt.Print( foo(_j).fn,"\n")  //0x401640     
    fmt.Print( foo(_q).fn,"\n")  //0x401640     
    // but correct fns called .. how ?
    foo(_j).fn()             //t           
    foo(_q).fn()             //q           

    // same thing again ...
    _fj := foo(_j).fn         
    _fq := foo(_q).fn         
    // both pointers same .. as above
    fmt.Print( _fj,"\n")         //0x401640    
    fmt.Print( _fq,"\n")         //0x401640    
    // correct fns called .. HOW !
    _fj()                //t                          
    _fq()                //q           
}
```

The pointer are what i'm getting my machin, YMMV.
My question is .. what exactly does interface(struct) returns ?
and how does interface(struct).func , finds the original struct ... 
is there some thunk/stub magic going on here?

Answer (score 3):

From here: http://research.swtch.com/interfaces

[image]

> what exactly does `interface(struct)` return?

It creates a new interface value (like the one you see on top in the graphic), wrapping a concrete struct value.

> how does `interface(struct).func` find the original struct?

See the *data* field in the graphic. Most of the time this will be a pointer to an existing value. Sometimes it will contain the value itself if it fits, though.

In the *itable* you'll see a function table (where *fun[0]* is).

I assume that on your machine `0x401640` is the address of the respective pointers to `fn`, which is in that table for `foo`. Although this is best verified by someone working on the GC compiler suite.

Note that the behaviour you discovered is not strictly defined to be so. Compiler builders can take other approaches to implementing Go interfaces if they like to, as long as [the language semantics](http://golang.org/ref/spec) are preserved.

---

Edit to answer questions in the comments:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type foo interface {
    fn()
}

type t struct{}
type q struct{}

func (_i t) fn() { fmt.Print("t", "\n") }
func (_i q) fn() { fmt.Print("q", "\n") }

func main() {
    _j := t{}
    _j1 := t{}

    fmt.Println(foo(_j) == foo(_j))  // true
    fmt.Println(foo(_j) == foo(_j1)) // true
}
```

On the diagram you see 3 blocks:

- The one on the left side labeled *Binary* is a concrete type instance, like your struct instances `_j` and `_j1`.
- The one on the top center is an interface value, this one wraps (read: points to) a concrete value.
- The block on the right lower side is the interface definition for *Binary* underlyings. This is where the jump table / call forwarding table is (*itable*).

`_j` and `_j1` are two instances of the concrete type `t`. So there are two of the lower-left blocks somewhere in memory.

Now you decide to wrap both `_j` and `_j1` in interfaces values of type `foo`; now you have 2 of the top-center blocks somewhere in memory, pointing back at `_j` and `_j1`.

In order for the interface value to remember what its underlying type is and where the methods of those types are it keeps a **single** instance of the lower-right block in memory, to which both interface values for `_j` and `_j1` respectively point to.

In that block you have a jump table to forward method calls made on the interface values to the concrete underlying type's implementation. That's why both are the same.

It's worth mentioning that unlike Java and C++ (not sure about Python), all Go methods are static and the dot-call notation is only syntactic sugar. So `_j` and `_j1` don't have different `fn` methods, it's the same exact method called with another implicit first parameter which is the receiver on which the method is called.

Comment: if interface(struct_instance) creates a 'new interface value', will super(_j) == super(j) be false ? what about super(_j) == super(_j1) .. I think answer is inadequate. Thanx for giving the pointer to swtch.com.

Comment: I'm sorry python creeping in way ..  
1. foo(_j) == foo(_j) .. is this true ?
2. if _j1 is another instance of t, is foo(_j) == foo(_j1) true ?
I still fail to see how _fj and _fq have same pointer, and be different under the hood !